# How to add layer with ArcPy and retain feature class metadata (like Credits) in layer properties?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, layers, metadata

I have multiple feature classes in a geodatabase, each feature class has metadata including a Description, Credits, and other information. If I use the 'Add Data' button in ArcMap 10.1 to add one of feature classes then that metadata is imported into the layer description. Ie, I view the layer properties and Description, Credits, etc., are filled in. However, if I use arcpy and add the feature class using `MakeFeatureLayer_management` and `AddLayer` then that metadata is not imported.

Does anyone know if its possible to get that full functionality of feature classes and their description, credits, etc to load with arcpy? Am I doing something wrong? Or, must I export the metadata, read the sections I want, and add that text to the layer file?

As requested, a code sample is:

```py
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_to_blankmxd)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(featureclass_sde,activation+"_"+featureclass)
addLayer=arcpy.mapping.Layer(activation+"_"+featureclass)
addLayer.name=layername
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,addLayer)
```

The feature class to be inserted in the MXD is 'featureclass_sde' with full metadata. However, once its inserted all metadata is lost. At present I am exporting metadata as XML, parsing XML to get metadata elements (description, source, etc), and then inserting those elements into the MXD. It works but seems so.... wrong....

Comment: I would expect this to work so are you able to post some code for your steps to be tested, please?

Comment: Hey - old post, but did you end up filing this as a bug with ESRI?  I'm having this same issue with 10.3.1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this appears to be a bug with **AddLayer** and so I think you should report it to your local **[Esri Support](http://support.esri.com/en/)**.

I was able to reproduce it easily by creating a file geodatabase, creating a feature class within it, and then using Item Description to Edit its Metadata including Credits.

When I drag and dropped this feature class into the map it created a layer that had the Credits on the General tab of its Properties - as expected.

However, when I ran the code below (based on yours) and looked in ArcMap at the layer thus created by AddLayer the expected Credits were missing!

```
import arcpy

path_to_blankmxd = r"C:\temp\test.mxd"
featureclass_gdb = r"C:\temp\test.gdb\testFC"
activation = "XX2"
layername = "test"
featureclass = "Poly"

mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(path_to_blankmxd)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Layers")[0]
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(featureclass_gdb,activation+"_"+featureclass)

addLayer=arcpy.mapping.Layer(activation+"_"+featureclass)
addLayer.name=layername
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,addLayer)
mxd.save()
del mxd
```